# Processing Error

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I'm trying to make an oscilloscope with an Arduino and I uploaded this code that I got from a website (http://lawrencematthew.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/build-a-6-channel-oscilloscope-with-just-arduino/) You think the code would work as is, but when I run the code, it gives me errors. I tried to do a Google search and did not find a solution. I do not know much of anything about processing and I'm just using it for this mainly. I appreciate any help from people.

The error it gives is the following:
No vertex shaders available
and then under that the detailed compiler info is:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: No vertex shaders available
    at processing.opengl.PGL$PGLListener.init(PGL.java:2493)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:507)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:546)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:533)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:280)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:904)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:822)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:543)
    at processing.opengl.PGL.requestDraw(PGL.java:814)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1566)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2020)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Here is the code:

```
/*
  This is a basic serial arduinoscope.

  (c) 2009 David Konsumer <david.konsumer@gmail.com>

  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General
  Public License along with this library; if not, write to the
  Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330,
  Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 */

/*

Serial data comes in, in the format

1 23 34 4 5 76
1 23 34 4 5 76
1 23 34 4 5 76
1 23 34 4 5 76

(space seperates pin=data, LF-seperated frame data)

*/

import arduinoscope.*;
import processing.serial.*;

// this example requires controlP5
// http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/
import controlP5.*;


import processing.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.*;


// how many scopes, you decide.
Oscilloscope[] scopes = new Oscilloscope[4];
Serial port;
ControlP5 controlP5;

PFont fontLarge;
PFont fontSmall;

int LINE_FEED=10; 

int[] vals;

void setup() {
  size(800, 800, P2D);
  background(0);

  controlP5 = new ControlP5(this);

  // set these up under tools/create font, if they are not setup.
  fontLarge = loadFont("TrebuchetMS-20.vlw");
  fontSmall = loadFont("Uni0554-8.vlw");

  int[] dimv = new int[2];
  dimv[0] = width-130; // 130 margin for text
  dimv[1] = height/scopes.length;

  // setup vals from serial
  vals = new int[scopes.length];

  for (int i=0;i<scopes.length;i++){
    int[] posv = new int[2];
    posv[0]=0;
    posv[1]=dimv[1]*i;

    // random color, that will look nice and be visible
    scopes[i] = new Oscilloscope(this, posv, dimv);
    scopes[i].setLine_color(color((int)random(255), (int)random(127)+127, 255));


    controlP5.addButton("pause",1,dimv[0]+10,posv[1]+10,32,20).setId(i);
    controlP5.addButton("logic",1,dimv[0]+52,posv[1]+10,29,20).setId(i+50);
    controlP5.addButton("save",1,dimv[0]+92,posv[1]+10,29,20).setId(i+100);
  }

  port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 115200);

  // clear and wait for linefeed
  port.clear();
  port.bufferUntil(LINE_FEED);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);

  // int[] vals = getTestValuesSquare();
  // int[] vals = getTestValuesSin();

  for (int i=0;i<scopes.length;i++){
    // update and draw scopes

    scopes[i].addData(vals[i]);
    scopes[i].draw();

    // conversion multiplier for voltage
    float multiplier = scopes[i].getMultiplier()/scopes[i].getResolution();

    // convert arduino vals to voltage
    float minval = scopes[i].getMinval() * multiplier;
    float maxval = scopes[i].getMaxval() * multiplier;
    int[] values = scopes[i].getValues(); 
    float pinval =  values[values.length-1] * multiplier;

    // add lines
    scopes[i].drawBounds();
    stroke(255);

    int[] pos = scopes[i].getPos();
    int[] dim = scopes[i].getDim();

    line(0, pos[1], width, pos[1]);

    // add labels
    fill(255);
    textFont(fontLarge);
    text(pinval, width-60, pos[1] + dim[1] - 10);

    textFont(fontSmall);
    text("min: " + minval, dim[0] + 10, pos[1] + 40);
    text("max: " + maxval, dim[0] + 10, pos[1] + 48);

    fill(scopes[i].getLine_color());
    text("pin: " + i, dim[0] + 10,pos[1] + dim[1] - 10);
  }

  // draw text seperator, based on first scope
  int[] dim = scopes[0].getDim();
  stroke(255);
  line(dim[0], 0, dim[0], height);

  // update buttons
  controlP5.draw();

}

// handles button clicks
void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {
  int id = theEvent.controller().id();

  // button families are in chunks of 50 to avoid collisions
  if (id < 50){
    scopes[id].setPause(!scopes[id].isPause());
  }else if (id < 100){
    scopes[id-50].setLogicMode(!scopes[id-50].isLogicMode());
  }else if(id < 150){
    String fname = "data"+(id-100)+".csv";
    scopes[id-100].saveData(fname);
    println("Saved as "+fname);
  }
}

// handle serial data
void serialEvent(Serial p) { 
  String data = p.readStringUntil(LINE_FEED);
  if (data != null) {
    // println(data);
    vals = int(split(data, ' '));
  }
}


// for test data, you can comment, if not using
int d=0;
ControlTimer ct = new ControlTimer();


int[] getTestValuesSin(){
  int[] vals = new int[scopes.length];

  // this is test data
  if (d==45){
    d=0;
  }

  int sval = (int) abs(sin(d*2)*1023.0f);
  for (int i=0;i<scopes.length;i++){
    vals[i]=sval;
  }

  d++;

  return vals;
}

int oldtime;
int time;
boolean up=false;

int[] getTestValuesSquare(){
  int[] vals = new int[scopes.length];

  ct.setSpeedOfTime(25);
  oldtime=time;
  time = ct.second();  

  if (oldtime==time){
    up = !up;
  }

  for (int i=0;i<scopes.length;i++){
    if (up){
      vals[i]=1023;
    }else{
       vals[i]=0;
    }
  }

  return vals;
}
```

It seems to help decrease the number of errors when I add:

```
import processing.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.*;
```

Other than that, I've got absolutely no idea how to fix this.

Comment: That type of error typically means you don't have a modern video card installed, or you don't have the drivers installed for it.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks I never saw that one coming. Maybe it is because I'm running processing in Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: There should be plenty of tips on the Processing forum about Linux drivers...